# MVC3 Validation attribute: lost in reflection; sorta genericy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, generics, reflection, data-annotations

I am trying to write a `NotAttribute` validator attribute for my MVC3 project.  I want to use it like this:

```
[Not("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", typeof(Guid), ErrorMessage = "You must select a valid id.")]
public Guid ObjectId { get; set; }
```

Now I don't want to tie the `NotAttribute` to a `Guid`, but the object should be parseable from a string; I want to look for a `TryParse` method first, then a `Parse` method; if both should fail, and the type is not already a string, I want to throw an error.  So far, so good, no complications.

My class looks like this:

```
public class NotAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public Type PropertyType { get; set; }
    public string NotEqualTo { get; private set; }
    public bool IgnoreWhitespace { get; set; }
    public bool CaseInsensitive { get; set; }

    public NotAttribute(string notEqualTo)
    {
        NotEqualTo = notEqualTo;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (PropertyType == null) PropertyType = typeof(string);
        if (PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            //this is the easy case.  We can compare easy enough
            var leftSide = value.ToStringOrEmpty();
            var rightSide = NotEqualTo ?? string.Empty;

            if (IgnoreWhitespace)
            {
                leftSide = leftSide.Trim();
                rightSide = rightSide.Trim();
            }

            if (CaseInsensitive)
            {
                leftSide = leftSide.ToUpperInvariant();
                rightSide = rightSide.ToUpperInvariant();
            }

            if (leftSide != rightSide) return null; // all is well
        }

        var tryParseMethod = PropertyType.GetMethod("TryParse",
            Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null,
            new Type[] {typeof(string), PropertyType.MakeByRefType()}, null);

        //This is where I get lost


        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure my `tryParseMethod` will return a reference to the object method that I could theoretically invoke, but here's where I run into problems.

How would I invoke it, passing in a type determined at runtime?  This seems to be screaming for a generics implementation, but I have no idea where I could inject that here.  Also, once I have the value I need to compare against the "not" value, I need to somehow cast it at runtime, which also screams for generics.

How can I make this work?  Am I doing this completely the wrong way?

Comment: Why are you complicating your life with those Data Annotations? Just take a look at [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which has a [great integration](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) with ASP.NET MVC. You will see that validation has never been easier.

Comment: That doesn't seem to support custom unobtrusive client-side validation, or was my skimming of the page not deep enough?

Comment: It has the same support of unobtrusive client validation as the standard Data Annotation attributes. If you use custom validation logic, you need to implement the corresponding javascript. Personally I never bother with this. I directly write the jQuery.validate rules for the form without usnig the Microsoft unobtrusive library. Way too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a static method, so you should just be able to invoke it without needing an instance of a class of the type `PropertyType` to invoke on (See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx)). So, you can just call `Invoke` on `tryParseMethod`.

However, the `TryParse` method itself will need an instance of a class of the type `PropertyType` as it's `out` parameter though, so you'll need to use `System.Activator.CreateInstance()` for that.

So, presumably something like

```
var parsedObject = System.Activator.CreateInstance(PropertyType);
bool parseSuceeded = tryParseMethod.Invoke(null, new [] { value, parsedObject });
```

will do the job.